# Did Krilin get god ki?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the last episode of Dragon Ball Super I was under the impression that Krilin could have gotten god ki. His ki was drawed differently, and he mentions that he has to control his energy for enemies not to notice him, just like Vegeta said he had to control his ki to not overflow when he acquired god ki for the fist time and god ki is not sensed by non gods. Now it was a thought that it lasted a few seconds in my mind, but now I've just seen that several youtubers are talking about the same in their videos, that it seems Krilin got god ki or became a human god. Is there any proof that what he did is god ki or it isnt god ki?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simply no**. Krillin may became stronger than before because he has mentally conquered his biggest fears, but I can ensure you that he did not achieved god form, for now. The aura you're seeing on Krillin might be his unique aura since he successfully controlled his ki on the remote island. It wasn't surprising anymore to see characters have different ki color/shape/control than usual. For example:

**1. [Pseudo / False Super Saiyan](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Pseudo_Super_Saiyan)**

First appearance in the 4rd movie of DBZ, while undergoing his battle against Lord Slug. Goku's anger causes him to gain massive increase in power to quickly overwhelm Lord Slug. A real super saiyan transformation should turn his hair into yellow.

[image]

**2. [Chi-chi's Kaioken-like red aura](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Chi-Chi#Personality)**

Chi-chi produces a Kaioken-like aura when Maron called her an old lady in the Garlic Jr. Saga. It's simply not Kaioken, there are lots of variety of [*ki colors*](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Ki#Appearances) including yellow, red, purple, orange, blue, green, pink, and black while most common color in the series is white.

[image]

**3. [Super Saiyan Rage](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Rage)**

The appearance is similar to Super Saiyan Blue but it's actually not. In the anime Dragon Ball Super, Future Trunks gained through intense rage, his muscles bulk up and hair spikes up even further, his irises and pupils are temporarily invisible similar to the Pseudo Super Saiyan and Legendary Super Saiyan forms.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No. Not at all. No way. Just because he had a ki silhouette instead of a ki flame does not mean he suddenly got some new power especially the ki of the gods.

Comment: you know, for some odd reason there is also a video from a month earlier theorizing Krilin was going to get god ki in a prediction for episodes 73-80. I dont know if the theory comes some info from a japanese source or what , but what a huge coincidence.

Comment: I agree with VISQL absolutely not. A human developing god-ki from training with Master Roshi? If that were the case Krillin wouldn't have been killed as many times as we was. More than likely what we saw in that ep was Krillin regaining the potential that was unlocked by Guru back on Namek. All that happened was he got back in shape, overcame his doubt and fear, and rekindled his warrior spirit. Let's not forget that this is all filler anyway.

Comment: Well, this is the first time they make this kind of training in a spiritual forest. Goku acquired god ki by the ritual, after he became super saiyan god he assimilated god ki by his own, so no training with gods is necessary to get god ki. I'm not stating krilin got god ki, i'm still wondering. Toei is giving fans what they fantasize with (return of kaioken, multiverse, fight between a freezer like character and piccolo, a broly like character, vegito super saiyan god and this could be another case of toei fan service)

Comment: Technically everything is a filler now. Toriyama isnt more involved in the manga than he is in the anime. The broly girl is based in an idea not created by toriyama

Comment: I think you are misusing the word filler here. Dragonball Super has no filler because it is not based on any actual source material to which it can add filler material.

Comment: @Pablo, the episode prediction stuff is horrible. I don't watch any because the titles are already that bad. Go back to some predictions from 3 or more weeks ago. Are they any good?

Comment: well, here it's the thing, neither the manga nor the anime are directly made by Toriyama. That's the difference with Dragon Ball Z and Dragon Ball were the manga had a special status since Toriyama was directly involved. Now both the anime and the manga are adaptations of Toriyama's ideas, so what are his ideas and what are Toyotaro's and Toei's ideas nobody knows

Comment: @VISQL yeah, there are predictions that works, like when they said there was going to be a new transformation with blue aura (super saiyan blue) or when they said vegito was going to be back, to name a few. And yes, a lot of them are also wrong.

Comment: @VISQL Dragon Ball Super is influenced by fans, this series has a strong influence of Dragon Ball Multiverse. This doesnt only happen in Dragon Ball or in an anime only, a lot of franchises (including sci fi and fantasy franchises) "borrows" ideas from fans. And Toyotaro who draws the official manga now is a former Dragon Ball fan artist from the fan made Dragon Ball AF story. It makes sense that fans can "predict" things, since the same company who makes Dragon Ball takes ideas from them.